# Метод Бабушкина

Tags: c

Объясните пожалуйста сортировку массива методом бабушкина, как она работает, ее алгоритм

Comment: Ну вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/articles/198114/) про нее рассказывается. Зачем она только нужна, убейте меня, не пойму...

Comment: [1](http://algolab.valemak.com/babushkin)  [2](https://habr.com/ru/articles/198114/)

Comment: подбираешь два числа, делишь меньшее на большее - получаешь готовую перестановку - какое число  исходного массива куда поместить в результате